# Something that logs as a function throws is not a function exception

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have the following code in a file called S3.js:

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

module.exports.copyItem = async(destination, source, key) => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    s3.copyItem({
        Bucket: destination,
        CopySource: source,
        Key: key
    }, (err, data) => {
        if(err){
            reject(err)
        }
        resolve(data)
    })
 })
}
```

And I have another file that needs to call this function copyItem:

```
module.exports.saveFile = async function(event, context, callback) {
    const tempPath = event.path;
    const objKey = event.key;
    const objectTitle = event.objectTitle;
    const id = uuid.v4();
    const deletePath = tempPath.slice(tempPath.indexOf('/') + 1);
    try {
      console.log(s3.copyItem)

      //Copies desired s3 object into destination
      let copyResponse = await s3.copyItem(bucket, tempPath, objKey);

      //builds and return a response
      var response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: {
          message: 'File successfully copied'
        }
      };
      return response;


    } catch (e) {
      console.log("catch!")
      console.log(e)
      console.log("catch")
      return {
        statusCode: 504,
        body: JSON.stringify(e)

      }
    }
```

This function is actually a lambda. When I invoke it, where it does console.log(s3.copyItem) it says: [AsyncFunction].

However, it always enter on catch statement, with an exception saying:
TypeError: s3.copyItem is not a function

Does anyone have a clue on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The error message says `s3.copy`, not `s3.copyItem`. But I don't see where you're using that.

Comment: @Barmar just updated the question. I never use copy, it's copyItem that I'm calling. My head is not working properly anymore bc of this lol

Comment: When you declare a function `async` it automatically returns a Promise. You shouldn't have an explicit `return new Promise` in it. I don't think this is related to the problem, but it still seems wrong.

Comment: How are you importing from `S3.js`?

Comment: The function in the AWS SDK is `s3.copyObject()`, not `s3.copyItem()`. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html

Comment: You made things confusing by using the same name `s3` for your module as the AWS SDK.

Comment: You're right. And yes, it was my fault for calling it the same as the SDK. How can I thank you?